# Incomplete implementations

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

I'm working on a project in Xcode and getting  an error from  `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and `incomplete implementation`. This is the main file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *FirstNameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *SurnameField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *EmailField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PasswordField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *ReenterPasswordField;


- (IBAction)RegisterAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

This is .m file:

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"


@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController
@synthesize scroller; 


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(340, 600)];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (user.email != nil) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)RegisterAction:(id)sender {
    [_FirstNameField resignFirstResponder];
    [_SurnameField resignFirstResponder];
    [_EmailField resignFirstResponder];
    [_PasswordField resignFirstResponder];
    [_ReenterPasswordField resignFirstResponder];
    [self checkFieldsComplete];

    [self checkFieldsComplete];
}

- (void) checkFieldsComplete {
    if ([_FirstNameField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_SurnameField.text isEqualToString:@""]|| [_EmailField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_PasswordField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_ReenterPasswordField.text isEqualToString:@""])  {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message: @"Make sure to complete every field" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        [self checkPasswordsMatch];
    }
}

- (void) checkPasswordsMatch {
    if (![_PasswordField.text isEqualToString:_ReenterPasswordField.text]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message: @"Passwords don't match" delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void) registerNewUser {
    PFUser *newUser;
    newUser.username = [NSString stringWithFormat: _FirstNameField.text, _SurnameField.text];
    newUser.email = _EmailField.text;
    newUser.password = _PasswordField.text;

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Welcome to Vici!");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login"
                                      sender:self];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"There was an error in registration");
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Can anyone point out a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a closing brace at `viewDidAppear`, and thus it's getting confused by the rest of the `@implementation` and complaining because it's not finding `RegisterAction` as a result. It's showing you the warning at `didReceiveMemoryWarning` because that was the first bit of code after your missing brace (which shows you how to find the issue in the future).

Add the missing brace and you should get past this error.

Comment: Thankyou very much, new to programming and I appreciate the help. Have a good day.

Comment: @user2778288 No problem. By the way, if you forgive me for some unsolicited advice on best practices, I'd suggest that in the future (a) at a matter of convention, your methods and variables should start with lowercase letters ... only class names should start with uppercase letters; and (b) `scroller` should probably be `weak`, not `strong`. In ARC, `IBOutlet` references should generally be weak (other that `IBOutletCollection` and top level controls, neither of which is the case here).